# Looping commands through a list of numbers in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to create a loop for the following commands:

```
cluster0.markers <- FindMarkers(object=NF.combined, ident.1 = 0, min.pct = 0.25)
cluster1.markers <- FindMarkers(object=NF.combined, ident.1 = 1, min.pct = 0.25)
cluster2.markers <- FindMarkers(object=NF.combined, ident.1 = 2, min.pct = 0.25)
```

I have tried the following:

```
cluster.markers <- list(c(0:2))
cluster.markers[[1]] <- FindMarkers(object=NF.combined, ident.1 =i, min.pct = 0.25)
```

But this command gives only one object (cluster.markers), which includes results for cluster1.markers only. How can I modify this loop so I get three objects (cluster0.markers, cluster1.markers and cluster2.markers)?

Comment: `cluster.markers <- lapply(1:3, function(i) FindMarkers(object=NF.combined, ident.1 = i, min.pct = 0.25))`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thanks, that worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using purrr:

```
find_markers <- function(i) {
    FindMarkers(object=NF.combined, ident.1 = i, min.pct = 0.25)
}

cluster_markers <- 0:2 %>%
    map(~find_markers(.))
```